# Is file compression a legit way to improve the performance of network communication for a large file

Tags: java, c++, performance, networking

i have a large file and i want to send it over the network to multiple consumers via pub sub method. For that purpose,  i choose to user `jeromq`. The code is working but i am not happy because i want to optimize it. The file is too large over than 2gb my question now is if i send a compressed file for example with gzip to consumers will the performance improve or the compress/decompress method introduces additional overhead so the performance will not be improved? What do you think?

In addition except for the compression is there any other technique to use?

For example, use erasure coding and splitting data into chunks and send chunks to consumers and then communicate to each other to retrieve the original one.

(Maybe my second idea is stupid or i dont have understand something correct please give me your directions.)

Comment: Seems to me like the second idea (if I understood it correctly) introduces an incredible amount of overhead, both in terms of performance and in terms of development complexity.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca isn't second idea is basically BitTorrent? Which is often used in gaming industry to deliever large amounts of data to large amount of customers even if update servers went down soon after new update?

Answer (score 2):

> if i send a compressed file for example with gzip to consumers will the performance improve or the compress/decompress method introduces additional overhead so the performance will not be improved?

Gzip has a relatively good compression ratio (though not the best) but it is slow. In practice, it is so slow that the network interconnect can be faster than compressing+decompressing a data stream. Gzip is only fine for relatively slow network. There are **faster compression algorithms** to do that, but with generally lower compression ratio. For example [LZ4](https://lz4.github.io/lz4/), is very fast for both compressing and decompressing a data stream in real time. There is a catch though: **the compression ratio is strongly dependent of the kind of file being sent**. Indeed, binary files or already compressed data will barely be compressed, especially with fast algorithm like LZ4 so compression will not worth it. For text-based data or ones with repeated pattern (or a reduced range of byte values), the compression can be very useful.

> For example, use erasure coding and splitting data into chunks and send chunks to consumers and then communicate to each other to retrieve the original one.

This is a common broadcast algorithm in distributed computing. This methods is used in distributed hash-table algorithms and also in MPI implementations (massively used on supercomputers). For example, MPI use a [**tree-based broadcast method**](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-broadcast-and-collective-communication/) when the number of machines is relatively big or/and the amount of data is also big. Note that this method introduce additional **latency** overheads that are generally small in your case unless the network has a very high latency. Distributed hash-table use more complex algorithm since they generally consider a not can fail (so they use dynamic adaptation) at any time and cannot be fully trusted (so they use checks like hashes and sometime even get data from multiple sources so to avoid malicious injection from specific machines). They also do not make assumption about the network structure/speed (resulting in an imbalanced download-speed).

Comment: Did you note that the question specifically mentions sending a file to multiple consumers? The price of compressing a datastream can be shared. gzip might be justified

Comment: @MSalters if you have a better solution feel free to post it thnx in advance

Comment: @Jérôme Richard Thanks for your wonderful answer i totally understand the first part. I have a quick question about the second part. For the erasure coding case can i send only a portion of split packets not the entire file to consumers to increase performance and then consumers retrieve the actual file even with fewer data packets? Is this a better approach than compressing and sending considering performance?

Comment: @MSalters Well the number of consumers matters indeed, but it needs to be pretty big so for gzip to be fast enough unless the network interconnect has an already pretty bad bandwidth. This is especially true with the tree-based method since each node only send a total data size of `O(n log c)` bytes where `c` is the number of consumer and `n` is the buffer size. The problem of gzip is the compression speed and not so much the decompression. The thing is that the faster the compression the better the scalability of the tree-based method (assuming the network scale which is generally the case)

Comment: @MixalisNavridis I am not sure to understand what do you mean. Sending packets is critical for performance as nodes receiving data can sent data to other nodes before the end of the file. This approach is not incompatible with compression: you can either compress packets or compress the whole stream like if the input file would have been a compressed archive. Compressing the full file generally results in a better compression ratio though.

Comment: @MixalisNavridis If your idea is to use error correcting codes so to send less data, then I do not think it can operate faster unless the remote nodes already have some information about the file to be received. In the end, the total amount of information about the file should not be significantly smaller than without error correcting system. In fact, if it would work well, I think it would be included in compression methods. The general idea with error correcting codes is to duplicate part of the information in a non-trivial way so to reconstruct it which mean bigger data in the end.